# Passar valor de txtBox para Label (entre forms do Windows Form) - Porém, string fica null

Tags: c#

Boa tarde, estou a alguns dias quebrando a cabeça aqui. Estou desenvolvendo um app com 2 forms (telas). Na tela inicial é a de login, e a segunda tela é o app em si. Eu quero pegar o nome informado pelo usuário no TxtBox da tela inicial, e passar para uma label da segunda tela, ficando: Bem vindo(a) {nomedousuario}!

Eu debuguei o código, e por algum motivo, a variável labelWelcome, inicialmente, recebe o valor, porem, não recebe a variável, o modo correto seria: *labelWelcome.Text = $"Seja bem-vindo(a) {Username}";*

Porem, ela recebe somente: *labelWelcome.Text = $"Seja bem-vindo(a)";*

**DETALHE:** A var Username recebe sim o valor do FORM1, porquê será que não está indo no Label do FORM2?

Segue lógica que utilizei para passar os valores:

```
**FORM1 (LOGIN):**
                // Método para abrir a nova tela
                private void FormLogado()
                {
                Application.Run(new CronogramaLogado(btn_login.Text));
                }

                *// Codificação para abrir nova tela
                Logado = new Thread(FormLogado);
                Logado.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                
                // String que recebe o nome do usuário da txtbox
                string nomeusuario = btn_login.Text;
                // instanciação da tela 2 chamada CronogramaLogado, e passando o valor do nome do user
                CronogramaLogado nome = new CronogramaLogado(nomeusuario);

                // "this.Close() fecha a tela anterior, e mantém somente a nova aberta"
                this.Close();

                // Abre a nova tela
                Logado.Start();*
```

**FORM 2 (APP APÓS LOGAR)**:

```
public partial class CronogramaLogado : Form
{
    public string Username;
    // Obrigando passar o valor username quando chamar a segunda tela
    public CronogramaLogado(string username)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Username = username;
        labelWelcome.Text = $"Seja bem-vindo(a) {Username}";
        // Método para gerar as colunas assim que a tela é aberta
        GerarColunas();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma que eu uso para passar Objetos entre telas, é passar o form1 no form2.

```
                public string nomeusuario = "";

                private void FormLogado()
                {
                   Application.Run(new CronogramaLogado(btn_login.Text));
                }

                *// Codificação para abrir nova tela
                Logado = new Thread(FormLogado);
                Logado.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                
                // String que recebe o nome do usuário da txtbox
                nomeusuario = btn_login.Text;
                // instanciação da tela 2 chamada CronogramaLogado, e passando o valor do nome do user
                CronogramaLogado nome = new CronogramaLogado(this); // aqui eu passo o 
                                                                    // form 1

                this.Close();

                // Abre a nova tela
                Logado.Start();
```

AQUI O FORM 2

```
public partial class CronogramaLogado : Form
{
    // Obrigando passar o valor username quando chamar a segunda tela
    public CronogramaLogado(FormLogado form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        labelWelcome.Text = $"Seja bem-vindo(a) {form1.nomeusuario }";
        // Método para gerar as colunas assim que a tela é aberta
        GerarColunas();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção! Problema foi resolvido.

Comment: isso pode resolver, mas é um exagero passar todo um objeto sendo que só precisa de uma string, seria muito mais fácil passar só a string

Comment: Você poderia me dar um exemplo de como ficaria passando só a string?

Answer (score 0):

Pode criar uma propriedade no Form e setar esse valor ao instanciar:

```
public class CronogramaLogado
{
   public string UsuarioLogado { get; set; }
}

private void FormLogado() 
{ 
    var cronograma = new CronogramaLogado
    {
       UsuarioLogado = btn_login.Text;
    };
    Application.Run(cronograma); 
}
```

Depois pode ler a property no form "CronogramaLogado".

```
private void CronogramaLogado_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelWelcome.Text = $"Seja bem-vindo(a) {UsuarioLogado}";
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo ainda. Em " var cronograma = CronogramaLogado " diz que não posso usar o CronogramaLogado no contexto fornecido. Da forma que eu fiz acima as vars da Form2 recebem o valor, porem, na hora de passar para o label, não passa a var =/

Comment: ah no meu exemplo faltou o new :) já editei a pergunta